# Any way to get 1 minute data using Zipline

Tags: python, zipline

I am using Zipline in an iPython Notebook to back test. However, I am fairly new to the library and was wondering if their was anyway to add 1 minute data. Currently I am able to receive 1 day open, high, low, close, etc. using the following code:

```
start = datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, pytz.utc)
end = datetime(2015,6,30,0,0,0,0, pytz.utc)

data = load_bars_from_yahoo(stocks=["AAPL"], start=start, end=end); data.save('talk_px.dat')
```

Is there anyway i could change the frequency from 1 day to 1 minute?

Answer (score 0):

you probably already figured out the answer, but just for reference the `run_algo.py` command you use to kick everything off features the `--data-frequency` parameter to request daily/minute data:

```
usage: run_algo.py [-h] [-c FILE] [--algofile ALGOFILE] [--data-frequency {minute,daily}] [--start START] [--end END] [--capital_base CAPITAL_BASE] [--source {yahoo}] [--symbols SYMBOLS] [--output OUTPUT]
```

Source: [Zipline beginner tutorial](http://www.zipline.io/tutorial/)